# What does SetEnvironmentVariable do

Tags: c#

On a web site I took over from someone else - this line appears before loading a crystal report into a report viewer

```
System.Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("TMP", @"C:\Temp");
```

It does not get mentioned again - apart from in an error message further down the page which seems to simply report that 'TMP' equals C:\Temp

What does that line actually do?

Here is the full code:

```
ReportDocument ViewReport = new ReportDocument();
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        string ReportPath = Server.UrlDecode(Request["Path"]);
        System.Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("TMP", @"C:\Temp");
        ViewReport.Load(@ReportPath);
        ViewReport.SetDatabaseLogon(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ReportsUser"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ReportsPassword"]);
        CrystalReportViewer1.Height = 640;
        CrystalReportViewer1.Width = 1100;
        CrystalReportViewer1.BestFitPage = false;
        CrystalReportViewer1.PrintMode = CrystalDecisions.Web.PrintMode.ActiveX;
        CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = ViewReport;
        CrystalReportViewer1.RefreshReport();
    }
    catch (Exception err)
    {
        string Err = "Error :-" + err.Message;
        Err = Err + "Source :-" + err.Source;
        Err = Err + "Inner Error :-" + err.InnerException.Message.Replace("\r", "");
        Err = Err + "Path not found :-" + Server.UrlDecode(Request["Path"]);
        Err = Err + " TMP=" + System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("TMP");
        string Message = "<script> alert(' " + Err + "');</script>";
        Response.Write(Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try to google it? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z46c489x.aspx

Comment: Read about [Environment Variables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable)

Comment: Check this link http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/178713-working-with-environment-variables-in-c%23/

Comment: I did read up on it first. But in the code I am looking at, I could not see the point of it. So I wondered if it had some sort of global affect on which directory was used for storing temporary files.

Comment: @NetStarter - would that line globally change where .net stores temporary files?

Comment: What does **globally** exactly means ?? I didn't get it,By setting Environment Variables you just say that save my temporary files/INformation require to run a process in this path with this particular variable name

Comment: @netStarter - by globally I mean - by setting the 'TMP' EnvironmentVariable to be 'C:\Temp' on a page that displays a Crystal Report in a Crystal Report Viewer, would, on another page, when a web service is being called, asp.net save the temporary serialization assembly in 'C:\Temp' instead of in the asp.net directory?

Answer (score 1):

An environment variable is a variable that is global on your computer for all processes. I will take a wild guess and say that your report viewer will need to store temporary files. It will ask the operating system for a place to store them. The operating system will look up it's variables, in this case one that is named "TMP" and return the value of it to the report viewer. The report viewer will then happily store it's temporary files there.

The line tells the operating system that there is a variable name TMP with the value C:\Temp.

The reportviewer will probably ask the operating system for the value of TMP to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

An environment-variable is a way for applications to determine for example paths to certain directory without explicitly knowing those.
For example, if you have a program that needs to unzip temporary files to do an installtion-routine, it can ask the system for the environment variable `TMP` and gets the path from the system. This makes applications independent from the actual systems, because someone might have a `TMP`-directoy called `C:\Temp` and someone else might have this on `D:\Temp`.

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable)

```
Environment variables are a set of dynamic named values that can affect the way 
running processes will behave on a computer
```

Comment: And if someone does not have a folder called 'TMP'?

The reason I asked the question is because the code I have inherited makes no sense - it creates an EnvironmentVariable but never uses it. i.e. it does not refer to it again when it needs a path.

So I wondered if it did something globally.

Comment: `TMP` is not the folder, but the environment variable. `TMP` is a standard-variable that comes in every Windows. Removing it might give your applications a hard time and make them crash or abort their operations.

Comment: @MartinSmellworse I'm fairly certain the code you inherit uses `Path.GetTempPath()` or something similar.

Comment: @bash.d - I don't want to remove it, I just want to know if that line affects things globally. The line, as it were, having been run once - would this affect where .net stores temporary files.

Comment: @Nolonar - no, that is definitely not used. There are only 10 lines on the page. One of them is the line I posted. The only other reference to TMP is in an error message in a catch block

Comment: @MartinSmellworse Maybe `Path.GetTempFileName()`? It may look like it's just generating a random name, but it actually creates a file with random name within the temp folder and returns the file's path. Frankly, I don't know. If you want us to explain to you why that line was used, you might want to post the entire code, or a link to it.

Answer (score 0):

> **Environment variables**

Environment variables are a set of dynamic named values that can affect the way running processes will behave on a computer.

They can be said in some sense to create the operating environment in which a process runs. For example, an environment variable with a standard name can store the location that a particular computer system uses to store temporary files — this may vary from one computer system to another. A process which invokes the environment variable by (standard) name can be sure that it is storing temporary information in a directory that exists and is expected to have sufficient space.[1]
In almost all operating systems each process has its own private set of environment variables. By default, when a process is created it inherits a duplicate environment of its parent process, except for explicit changes made by the parent when it creates the child. Running programs can access the values of environment variables for configuration purposes.

**Examples of environment variables include:**

Path - lists directories the shell searches, for the commands the user may type without having to provide the full path.

Temp - location where processes can store temporary files

UserProfile - indicate where a user's home directory is located in the file system.

AppData{DeveloperName\AppName} - for storing application settings.

> List of Windows environment variables

AllUsersProfile

AppData

CD

ClientName

CmdCmdLine

CmdExtVersion

ComSpec

CommonProgramFiles

ComputerName

Date

ErrorLevel

HomeDrive

HomePath

LocalAppData

LogonServer

Number Of Processors

OS

Path

PathExt

Processor Architecture

Processor Identifier

Processor Level

Processor Revision

ProgramFiles

Prompt

Random

SessionName

SystemDrive

SystemRoot

Temp

Time

Tmp

UserDnsDomain

UserDomain

UserName

UserProfile

WinDir

> by globally I mean - by setting the 'TMP' EnvironmentVariable to be
>   'C:\Temp' on a page that displays a Crystal Report in a Crystal Report
>   Viewer, would, on another page, when a web service is being called,
>   asp.net save the temporary serialization assembly in 'C:\Temp' instead
>   of in the asp.net directory?

The temporary folder will only store process related data it will not store assembly and other things.

More at http://environmentvariables.org/